# Document Changes Renders Some Functions Inert

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

Forgive the sloppy code - this is a prototype and I'll be simplifying it later. I've included the whole file so you can see the problem in context.

The problem though is a simple one:

The `$(document).on("click", "#submit-geqqo", function () {`... works fine. However it seems to render functions like the `$(document).on("click", ".favorite-status", function ()` unable to perform their full job, or completely inert.

I'm assuming that some change in the document tree is causing the other functions to misbehave.

**How can I make it so that the document is accessible by all functions when content is replaced?**

THE CODE:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $(function () {

        $(document).on("click", "#submit-geqqo", function () {

            var data = {
                action: 'geqqo_ajax',
                geqqo_new: tinymce.get('geqqo-new').getContent()
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                //alert(response);

                tinymce.get('geqqo-new').setContent('');

                $('#geqqo-editor').modal('hide');

                $('#geqqo-editor').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('#timeline').prepend(response);
                    $('#timeline').children(":first").hide().show('blind');
                    $('.comment-form input[type=submit]').addClass("btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block");
                });

            });

        });

        $(document).on("click", ".delete-status", function () {
            var id = $(this).data("delete-status");

            var data = {
                action: 'geqqo_ajax',
                geqqo_delete: id
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

                $('#geqqo-status-' + id).effect('blind', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            });
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".comment-remove", function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var comment_id = $(this).data("delete-comment");

            var data = {
                action: 'geqqo_ajax',
                comment_id: comment_id
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

                var rjson = $.parseJSON(response);

                $('#comment-' + rjson['comment_id']).effect('drop', {
                    direction: 'up'
                }, function () {
                    $(this).hide('fold').remove();
                });

            });
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".favorite-status", function () {
            this.blur();
            var id = $(this).data("favorite-status");
            var toggle = $(this).data("favorite-status-toggle");

            var data = {
                action: 'geqqo_ajax',
                geqqo_favorite: id,
                toggle_fav: toggle
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

                var rjson = $.parseJSON(response);

                var border = 'transparent';
                var background = 'transparent';
                var color = '#aaa';

                if (rjson['toggle'] == 0) {
                    border = '#DDDDDD';
                    background = '#fff';
                    color = '#E87600';
                }

                $('#fav-' + rjson['fav_id']).animate({
                    color: color,
                    backgroundColor: background,
                    borderBottomColor: border,
                    borderTopColor: border,
                    borderLeftColor: border,
                    borderRightColor: border,
                }, 700);

            });

            var fav_count = $('#geqqo-favorite-count-' + id).html();

            if (toggle == 1) {
                $(this).data("favorite-status-toggle", 0);
                $('#geqqo-favorite-count-' + id).html(+fav_count + 1);
            } else {
                $(this).data("favorite-status-toggle", 1);
                $('#geqqo-favorite-count-' + id).html(+fav_count - 1);
            }

        });

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: None at all. But for instance one function which should trigger an ajax call simply "posts" causing a doc refresh after the `$(document).on("click", "#submit-geqqo", function ()` is fired.

Comment: In a nutshell, some functions fail to work properly after this has been fired. Is there any causes that can stop jquery from recognizing or working with other elements after appending data?

Comment: Not as far as I know, if you're using `on()` (assuming your jQuery version supports it - I think the equivalent used to be `live()`), which you seem to be